# Bayes estimate under absolute loss function

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, bayesian, estimation, median

Consider a Bayesian model where the prior distribution is $\lambda(\theta) = \frac{2}{(1+\theta)^3}$, $\theta > 0$ and $X\sim U(0,\theta).$ Find the Bayes estimate $\delta(x)$ if the loss function is $L(\theta, d) = |d-\theta|.$

I know that $\theta\mid X\sim f(x, \theta) = \frac{2}{\theta(1+\theta)^3}$ and the bayes estimate under absolute loss function is the median of the posterior distribution. However, I got stuck on finding the median. Can anyone help me out? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The model is uniform in $[0;1]$ so the posterior is

$$f(\theta\mid\mathbf{x})=\frac{2}{(1+\theta)^3}$$

To calculate the median is enough to calculate

$$\int_0^\theta \frac{2}{(1+u)^3}\,du=\frac{1}{2}$$

That easily leads to $\hat{\theta}=\sqrt{2}-1$

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I just found I have made a mistake in the problem above. Actually X~U(0, $\theta$), and the integral becomes very complex.

Comment: @ZHuang : in this case I think you have to understand which distribution your posterior is. The posterior you found must be normalized. If the model was uniform $U(0;\frac{1}{\theta})$ your poserior will be an inverse beta...otherwise I do not know. Please pay more attention when writing before posting